# Ingress or LoadBalancer on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

I'm wondering whether to use an Ingress or LoadBalancer to expose services on Azure AKS.

I have successfully used both, but I cannot really choose. On one side, an Ingress allows us to have a single public IP address, but on the other end it factorizes all the routes inside one Ingress so deployment means impacting all the routes.

Would you recommend:

- a common Ingress for all applications
- an Ingress for each application;
- a LoadBalancer for each service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create an ingress resource along side each application, that way you can modify individual ingress resources without impacting other applications. Load balancers do not allow you to do anything meaningful with your traffic.

With ingress you can use cert-manager, external-dns, ssl offloading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use an Ingress for each application. This allows for any updates to it to be specified as a separate deployable unit. If there is a need for separate public IPs, you can have multiple ingress controllers for different namespaces/environments.